# Indexing multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm familiar with multidimensional arrays being accessed as such:  **arr[rows][cols]**  which makes sense to me when I imagine it as a grid or coordinate system and locating points. But I'm confused about the line below. I understand it is picking up a pointer to some **struct** located in the array of structures I just have a hard time imagining which location this could represent in terms of the coordinate system I'm used to...its a bitmap by the way and SOMETHING is a pixel.

```
//what does this line mean   SOMETHING *o = original + row*cols + col;



for (row=0; row < rows; row++)
 for (col=0; col < cols; col++) {
  SOMETHING* o = original + row*cols + col;
  SOMETHING* n = (*new) + row*cols + (cols-1-col);
  *n = *o;
}
```

Comment: That's a poor choice of variable names.

Answer (score 5):

Think about how arrays are laid out in memory. A multidimensional array is just an array of arrays, so say you had an array like `SOMETHING[10][10]`.

The memory layout would be:

```
[0][0], [0][1], .. [0][9], [1][0], [1][1].. [9][9]
```

This actually is exactly the same as allocating `sizeof(SOMETHING)*100`.

What the line `SOMETHING* o = original + row*cols + col;` is saying is "make a pointer to object of type `SOMETHING`".

The pointer address should be:

- the memory address of original,
- add row times cols to it,

> which will place it at the start of a row,

- then add the specific column to it

> to get to the exact position of an object in the array

Comment: Note that for this to work the type of `original` needs to be `SOMETHING *` -- not a 2D array of `SOMETHING`.  Otherwise the pointer arithmetic increments by rows instead of `SOMETHING`s, and gives an array (representing a row) instead of a single `SOMETHING` element.

Answer (score 5):

A two dimensional array such as:

```
{{00,01,02,03},
 {10,11,12,13},
 {20,21,22,23},
 {30,31,32,33}}
```

Will be placed in memory in order. Just like this:

```
 {00,01,02,03,10,11,12,13,20,21,22,23,30,31,32,33}
```

So, when you access the array with `a[i][j]`, you can also access the array with

`a + i *(ELEMENTS_IN_ROW) + j`

Answer (score 1):

There is a pointer named `original` which probably sits at the origin (`[0][0]`). You are doing simple arithmetic to point to the current co-ordinate.

Suppose it's a 5x5 array and you are now in the 3rd row, 4th column (`[2][3]`)

To reach `[2][3]` from origin , you have to travel:

- 5 units in the first row
- 5 units in the second row
- 3 units in the third

  ---

Total of 13 units.

`row*cols + col` gives you `2*5 + 3` ie. `13`

So if you move `row*cols + col` units from `origin`, you get to your current location.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is that the 2-D grid you're imagining is actually represented as contiguous, **linear** memory.

So to access a coordinate at index `(r,c)` you need to start at the base address of the array, then skip to the `r`-th row by multiplying the row index `(r)` by the number of columns in each row--again, we're moving in a linear direction. This will bring you to the first column of the r-th row. From here you increment the pointer by c columns and you're at your destination.

So in your code, I'm assuming `original` is the start of your array. Therefore the line:

```
original + row*cols + col
```

is doing exactly what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

row-column coordinates tend to lead to some confusion when mixed with something different... for example with the typical image coordinate system, where the origin is the top-left corner.

a matrix has coordinates indicated as (row, column). That's equivalent to (y,x) in the coordinates of the image: by incrementing rows you go down; incrementing columns, right.

In your code the 2D space, is just following the typical convention of both C (row-major) and of images (by lines). So you can read:

```
SOMETHING* o = original + row*cols + col;
```

as

```
SOMETHING* o = original + iy*width + ix;
```

note finally that this is the same of using static 2D arrys in C, so these would be equivalent:

```
original[NROWS][NCOLS];
...
SOMETHING *o = &original[row][col];
```

or

```
SOMETHING original[HEIGHT][WIDTH];
...
SOMETHING *o = &original[iy][ix];
```

with the very important limitation that in this case the dimensions must be known at compile time. In your case you are dealing with *dynamic bidimensional arrays*, that are not supported by the C language.

To conclude, being SOMETHING a pixel, let me guess...

```
struct SOMETHING {
  unsigned char r;
  unsigned char g;
  unsigned char b;
};
```

it means that any element addressed in one of the two ways is just 3 bytes long, and they are just arranged contiguous.